# Container positioning in a section with height:100% and width:100%

Tags: html, css

How can I properly position the greyish container in 'portfolio' section so that the same is always fully visible, even on smaller size screens. I want my 'portfolio' section to always have height and width:100% (just like the 'home' section with the photo background above) but the greyish container inside 'portfolio' section should not go behind the 'contact' section when the browser is shrinked.

When I add `#pagetwo{width: 80%;}` the greyish container flows nice when I shrink or stretch my browser size. Why can't I add the `#pagetwo{height:70%;}` property to the same place?

I added height:450px; but now the greyish container falls behind my 'contact' section and it looks messy?

How can I fix this and make everything flows nice and smoothly on all size of screens???

Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/zwwve/60/

Comment: You can't use percentual height for the grey container because the height of the whole page doesn't depend on the width of the browser window like width does (in most cases) but on the contents of the page. You can use javascript to dynamically change the height of the grey container on window resize.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am not good in JavaScript. Is there a way to fix this somehow else with css?

Comment: give your `.copy` that is the parent of `#pagetwo` a `100%` height. Then a percentual height of `#pagetwo` should work. Then you will have to adjust the contents of `#pagetwo` but this should be no problem I think.

Comment: Alright. I'll try that and will get back to you soon...

Comment: I added your suggestions and this is what I have now: http://jsfiddle.net/zwwve/66/